# What does supreme-court refer to?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is no tag excerpt or wiki for [supreme-court](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supreme-court), and as I see it, it can either be:

- The Supreme Court of the United States.
- The highest court in any given country (i.e. [any of these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supreme_court)).

Looking through the questions, it seems [there are 11 questions without the united-states tag](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supreme-court+-united-states). A quick glance reveals that most – if not all – are about the SCOTUS anyway.

At the very least, it would be good to disambiguate this in the tag excerpt.

---

It might also be a good idea to rename this tag to make the intent clearer from just the name. [supreme-court-of-the-united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supreme-court-of-the-united-states) is a bit long, and [scotus](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scotus) is somewhat obscure, but perhaps we could rename it to [us-supreme-court](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-supreme-court) or something similar?

Do we still want to add a country-agnostic supreme-court tag? An example of a question which could be tagged with a country-agnostic [supreme-court](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supreme-court) tag would be [this one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/11330/11249), as it's about the *Raad van State*, which is the supreme court in the Netherlands. Would this add value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All United States questions should be tagged [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states), so my preferred solution would be to just add the missing tag to nine of the questions.  I did two today.  So as not to dump nine questions to the top of the front page at once, I plan to wait to do the others.

Note that two of the questions refer to the Supreme Court of Canada and are properly tagged [canada](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canada).

If the US questions are tagged properly, then I don't see that we need separate tags for each country.  And even if we added [us-supreme-court](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-supreme-court), we still should [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) for those who want to mask out the many US questions.