# Make le tag [presidential-election] specific again? Oui? Non?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [presidential-election](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presidential-election) has been used for both the US 2016 presidential election and the 2017 French presidential election. I find this not only ambiguous, but worse still, I find it confusing, because you'd expect "presidential election" to refer to only one specific presidential election.

Do elections for a president in one country have much in common with elections for a president in another country, beyond what two elections in any two countries of any flavour, presidential or non-presidential, would have?

I'd rather have a tag for a specific position (eg "us-presidential-election"), or abandon it and only use "specific-elections".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way I've always used it is to combine it with another tag: [presidential-election](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presidential-election) *and* [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) or [france](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/france) (or any other country).

I'm not sure if splitting it all out in [us-presidential-election](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-presidential-election), [french-presidential-election](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french-presidential-election), etc. is very useful. Besides, we'd probably still need [presidential-election](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presidential-election) for tags about Presidential elections *in general* which aren't strictly tied to a specific country (an example of such a question would be [Why do countries have term limits on Presidents and Prime Ministers?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/15906/11249)).

It's the same as for example the "xml" tag on Stack Overflow. On its own, it won't be very useful most of the time (although it *could* be if you have a question about the XML spec), but you can combine it with other tags (e.g. Python, Java, etc.) to get a useful combination.

Someone should probably go though [this list](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presidential-election+-united-states+-france) and add some united-states tags there. I'll do that over the course of the next few days (so the homepage won't be swamped with old questions).

[specific-elections](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-elections) seem entirely redundant to me and a "metatag" more than anything else.

Also see: [What does supreme-court refer to?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2822/11249)