# Rename the [25th-amendment] to the full [twenty-fifth-amendment]

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-renaming

Right now, there are 8 tags about specific amendments in the US constitution. All of those, *except* the [25th-amendment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/25th-amendment) use the word, instead of the number. It would be more consistent to rename the tag to [twenty-fifth-amendment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twenty-fifth-amendment). If this doesn’t work, or is a bad  idea for whatever reason, I alternatively propose we rename all of the other tags with amendment in their names to use numbers instead of words.

Comment: And should we add the number version as a synonym too?

Comment: I don’t see any downside, but there might be one I don’t know of @JJJ.

Comment: Yea, as far as I can tell the only downside would be that many tags show up if there are a lot of matches. I don't think that's a problem, at least not now, so I'll change it to the full text format and add the numerical versions as synonyms on all these tags.

Comment: Personally, it seems better to me to have the numeric versions as the primary form of the tag, with the written-out versions as synonyms. (Or rather, I don't see a benefit to having the written-out form be the primary version of the tag.) That said, I'll leave that decision to the community and the mods here :)

Comment: @V2Blast may I ask why you think that the numeric version would be better? (I personally don’t care either way, as long as it is consistent.)

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica: It just seems simpler and easier to read to me - and I think it better reflects the usage of those terms in practice, though that's just a guess on my part. ...Google Ngrams does suggest that my assumption is incorrect - the written-out versions seem more common for pretty much any number, e.g. "Thirteenth Amendment" vs. "13th Amendment". Carry on as you were, I suppose :P