# How to tag questions about electoral colleges that are not in the USA?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [electoral-college](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electoral-college) tag wiki says:

> In the United States, the President is not elected directly by popular vote, but by electors chosen by each state, which can sometimes produce a different outcome from the popular vote. Use with the [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) tag

It seems this tag is claimed to be specific to the USA.  Then how should we tag questions about electoral colleges outside the USA?

There are several other countries with electoral colleges.  For example, in The Netherlands, there is an [electoral college for the senate elections](https://english.kiesraad.nl/elections/electoral-colleges-for-the-senate).  The [college electing popes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/College_of_Cardinals) arguably is one as well.  [Wikipedia lists a few more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_college_(disambiguation))

Comment: What questions would be tagged with this that are not about the United States? It is a very specific term used in the constitution.

Comment: @JoeW Questions about the [Dutch electoral college](https://english.kiesraad.nl/elections/electoral-colleges-for-the-senate), for example.  See [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/77644/130), where I have been naughty and used the [tag:electoral-college] tag for a non-US question.

Comment: That should be edited into the question.

Comment: @JoeW Ok, done :)

Comment: The consensus is that [presidential-election] can be used for the presidential election of multiple countries, and allowing [electoral-college] to be used for multiple countries would be consistent with that. https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/make-le-tag-presidential-election-specific-again-oui-non

Answer (score 10):

I propose editing the [electoral-college](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electoral-college) tag wiki to read something like:

> Some elections are not decided directly by popular vote but by a group of electors. These electors can be selected in a number of ways, including being elected by popular vote. Use with a relevant country tag.

Since the [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) tag is mentioned current tag wiki, old questions should already be tagged correctly.

This would bring the tag in line with other tags that are mostly but not entirely US-focused like [primaries](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primaries) or [senate](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senate).

Comment: I voted to reject the *tag wiki excerpt edit* due, in part, to the following,
"If the electors have other resonsibilities as well, consider using a tag like [parliament] instead." Those viewing the excerpt from a US perspective may be confused by the reference to parliament (which was not part of the suggestion above).

Answer (score 6):

The electoral college for the US president is a pretty unique election mechanism that doesn't have too much to do with other kinds of electoral colleges. And whenever there is a US presidential election, we get a ton of interest in this tag. But the other electoral colleges mentioned here are far less interesting to the users of this community (at least judging how often they are mentioned in questions).

I think it might be prudent to rename the tag to [us-electoral-college](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-electoral-college). If any other political entity that's also named "electoral college" becomes relevant enough in the future to warrant a tag, we can create one specifically for that electoral college.